# Can't create iPad XIB with Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xcode4

Alright, I have a problem on my hands.  I'm trying to convert my project to a universal app for the iPhone and the iPad.  I'm trying to make iPad-specific versions of my XIB files.  As it's not possible to `Create iPad version using autoresizing masks` in Xcode 4, I assumed I'd just be able to pop my XIB into Xcode 3's version of IB, and let that do the magic.  No dice.  Here's the error I get when i try to open the XIB file in IB:

[image]

To be honest I don't know where to proceed from here.  I guess I could just resize my views manually, but that's quite tedious and I don't really have the time to be doing that.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was having trouble with XCode 4 and developing iOS apps as well. It seems like XCode4 is geared more towards Mac apps at the moment (anyone clarify)? I reverted back to XCode 3.2 for my iPhone and iPad apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a rather convoluted workaround.

First of all, duplicate your original project and then select your project info.  Right-click on your target, and select "Duplicate".

[image]

Xcode will then pop up this message.  Select "Duplicate and Transition to iPad".

[image]

Now Xcode converts the XIB files for you, and presents you with an iPad resources folder.

[image]

Now open these XIB files in the Finder, and append `~ipad` after the file name.

After doing so, copy these XIB files back into your **original** project, and then turn your project into a universal project by selecting from the dropdown in your target settings.

[image]

And you're done.  I found that really convoluted, and I'm hoping Apple can fix this huge usability problem soon.

Comment: Sorry,but I can't see the views adjusting according to Ipad resolutions despite of following all your steps :(

Comment: I mean all those iphone nib file views are on ipad nib views

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen. One way to fix this problem would be t completely remove the Xcode 4 Installation and re install it from scratch . And then re install it.

Use the following command to uninstall and re install Xcode 4

sudo [xcode-path]/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

PS: If you are creating projects in Xcode 4 that you also want to open in Xcode 3 make sure you keep Document Versioning section to Interface Builder 3.1